# Select a row of first non-null values

Tags: database, postgresql

I have the following table. How do I select the first non-null value of **reviewers** and **voting** column if they have the same **product_id**? The first here mean the first row sorting by **created_at**

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| product_id | reviewers | voting |     created_at      |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| B0021ZFV9M | null      | null   | 2015-03-20 00:34:09 |
| B0021ZFV9M | 4         | 3      | 2015-03-24 00:34:09 |
| B0021ZFV9M | null      | null   | 2015-04-13 00:55:51 |
| B0021ZFV9M | 30        | 4      | 2015-04-15 00:44:38 |
| B00JKO4CHO | null      | null   | 2015-09-17 00:41:40 |
| B00JKO4CHO | null      | null   | 2015-09-19 00:41:47 |
| B00JKO4CHO | 50        | 1      | 2015-09-21 00:41:31 |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Expected

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| product_id | reviewers | voting |     created_at      |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| B0021ZFV9M | 4         | 3      | 2015-03-20 00:34:09 |
| B0021ZFV9M | 4         | 3      | 2015-03-24 00:34:09 |
| B0021ZFV9M | 30        | 4      | 2015-04-13 00:55:51 |
| B0021ZFV9M | 30        | 4      | 2015-04-15 00:44:38 |
| B00JKO4CHO | 50        | 1      | 2015-09-17 00:41:40 |
| B00JKO4CHO | 50        | 1      | 2015-09-19 00:41:47 |
| B00JKO4CHO | 50        | 1      | 2015-09-21 00:41:31 |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  product_id,

  case
  when reviewers is null then (
    select reviewers from test 
    where product_id = a.product_id
      and created_at > a.created_at
      and reviewers is not null
    limit 1)
  else reviewers
  end as reviewers,

  case
  when voting is null then (
    select voting from test 
    where product_id = a.product_id
      and created_at > a.created_at
      and voting is not null
    limit 1)
  else voting
  end as voting,

  created_at
from test a;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/546dff/3

```
create table test (
  product_id varchar(20),
  reviewers int,
  voting int,
  created_at datetime
);

insert into test values 
 ('B0021ZFV9M',null      , null   ,'2015-03-20 00:34:09')
,('B0021ZFV9M',4         , 3      ,'2015-03-24 00:34:09')
,('B0021ZFV9M',null      , null   ,'2015-04-13 00:55:51')
,('B0021ZFV9M',30        , 4      ,'2015-04-15 00:44:38')
,('B00JKO4CHO',null      , null   ,'2015-09-17 00:41:40')
,('B00JKO4CHO',null      , null   ,'2015-09-19 00:41:47')
,('B00JKO4CHO',50        , 1      ,'2015-09-21 00:41:31');
```

Result:

```
| product_id | reviewers | voting |                  created_at |
|------------|-----------|--------|-----------------------------|
| B0021ZFV9M |         4 |      3 |     March, 20 2015 00:34:09 |
| B0021ZFV9M |         4 |      3 |     March, 24 2015 00:34:09 |
| B0021ZFV9M |        30 |      4 |     April, 13 2015 00:55:51 |
| B0021ZFV9M |        30 |      4 |     April, 15 2015 00:44:38 |
| B00JKO4CHO |        50 |      1 | September, 17 2015 00:41:40 |
| B00JKO4CHO |        50 |      1 | September, 19 2015 00:41:47 |
| B00JKO4CHO |        50 |      1 | September, 21 2015 00:41:31 |
```

EDIT:

To update old data, you could do this:

```
-- create a duplicate empty table
create table test1 like test;

-- insert good data into this duplicate table
insert into test1 
  select
  product_id,

  case
  when reviewers is null then (
    select reviewers from test 
    where product_id = a.product_id
      and created_at > a.created_at
      and reviewers is not null
    limit 1)
  else reviewers
  end as reviewers,

  case
  when voting is null then (
    select voting from test 
    where product_id = a.product_id
      and created_at > a.created_at
      and voting is not null
    limit 1)
  else voting
  end as voting,

  created_at
from test a;

-- remove data from original table
truncate table test;

-- re-insert good data into original table
insert into test select * from test1;

-- drop the duplicate table
drop table test1;
```

Make a backup of test (original) table before you try this.

Comment: How about update query? It mean, how to update data to fix old data?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct on (a.product_id, a.created_at)
    a.product_id, 
    coalesce(a.reviewers, b.reviewers) reviewers,
    coalesce(a.voting, b.voting) voting,
    a.created_at
from a_table a
left join a_table b
    on a.product_id = b.product_id 
    and b.reviewers notnull
    and b.created_at > a.created_at
order by 1, 4;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/32ffc/2).

Note: it is assumed that if `reviewers` is `not null` then `voting` is `not null` too.